# Change Modified Date and User in Versions

Tags: 2010, powershell, versioning

We have document libraries in Sharepoint 2010 with incorrect modified dates and users (they were imported from somewhere). I thought, I could correct them with Powershell, but it does not work the way I tried and I cannot figure out what  is wrong.

It is easy for list items:

```
$item["Editor"] = $newuser
$iten["Modified"] = $newdate
$item.update()
```

I thought, I could adapt this to versions. I can read the properties, but when I try to assign a new value, it throws an error:

```
Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion.
At line:1 char:10
+ $version[ <<<< "Modified"]=$newdate
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Modified:String) [], RuntimeE
xception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to change these values?

Comment: Can you share what code you used to update versions. Moreover, it should not be `$item.update()`. It should rather be `$item.SystemUpdate()`

Comment: I have not had the chance to update (yet). The error is thrown before. I cannot even assign the value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change item version properties as `SPListItemVersion.this[string]` indexer is read only. That is, whereas this code is legal:

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
item["X"] = "a";
```

The below code will throw error:

> Property or indexer
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemVersion.this[string]' cannot be
>   assigned to -- it is read only

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);                
SPListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions;
foreach(SPListItemVersion version in versions)
{
    version["Modified"] = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
}
```

Moreover, properties of `SPListItemVersion` are read only as well, like `SPListItemVersion.CreatedBy`

Comment: Is there no way to change these values?

Comment: I am afraid there isn't any way of doing this. At least I couldn't find one.

Comment: how about re-upload the documents and change the modified date of each one before uploading the next document

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a way to manipulate Versions dates via Powershell. Applies to SP2016/2019 (didn't test with an earlier version).
Maybe still useful for others:

```
$DateValue = "2013-01-01 10:05"
$doc["Modified"] = $DateValue
$doc["Created"] =  $DateValue
$doc.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
$doc.File.Publish("test")
```

The latest major version is set to ~10 years ago.

[image]